# 'Stackoverflow error' in Windows 7 64 bit web browser control with IE 8

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-8, browser, 64-bit, stack-overflow

A website opens up correctly in IE 8 in Windows 7 64 bit machine. This same website is being loaded in C# web browser control and results in 'Stackoverflow error at line xxxx' message box. This error message appears only in the windows web browser control and with IE 8 combination on 64 bit Windows 7 machine. The page loads correctly after displaying this message box.

Things that have already been tried without any success:

1. Feature browser emulation to set the browser control to use IE 8.
2. Adding Window_OnError handler to the Webbrowser's document's window object. This catches normal stack overflow errors due to recursive function calls in javascript. But, it does not catch this specific error on this website.
3. Updates to IE8 did not solve it. Upgrading to IE 9 solves the problem. But that would require making IE 9 a pre-requisite to the product. This is not preferred.
4. Firebug does not locate any issues with the page being displayed.
5. Disable script debugging is unchecked to avoid this issue but results in other script errors that show up in web browser control on Windows XP.

Additional information - The page contains framesets.

Is there any other option that could be tried to locate and solve the problem?

Comment: Can you get the traceback for the stackoverflow exception?

Comment: Do you mean stack trace from the Firebug?

Comment: Update - located the script file that shows the message 'Stackoverflow at line xxxx' when it is included. It is a dojo script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying multiple options, it seems like there is some issue with webbrowser control on 64 bit with IE 8 when an EXE is run in 64 bit mode. If the program is compiled with x86 mode, it works correctly without the message. This is like a work around. The error continues to appear in 64 bit process.

There also seems to be issues with the website as well.